# How to search a text through multiple urls

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, youtube, browser-automation

Ok so i've been struggling with this one for some time and can't seem to figure out how to do it.
I wanted to do a test with a bunch of youtube Urls i generated using a random string, basically i goes "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX"
XXX meaning the randomly generated sequence.

What i wanted to try was to differentiate the Urls between the "this video isn't available" from the ones that do work.

But i can't seem to find anywhere on the internet how to run a code that will go through the Urls and tell you which one contains the certain text from the others.

It seems to be a task that requires javascript but i'm not sure how i can use it to meet it.

For now i've been doing it hand to hand double clicking using Notepad++ but it's so tiring for my wrists lol.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add what have you tried in code? - you mention you use notepad, but, have you code any attempt for solve this requierement?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? And then once you invoke the function just catch the error if thrown and output the ids were applicable?

```
import fs from "fs";
import ytdl from "ytdl-core";

/**
 * @description Download a youtube video to a file for a given video id.
 * @param {string} videoId The youtube video id.
 * @param {string} outputPath The path to the output file.
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 * @example downloadVideo("videoId", "outputPath");
 */
export async function downloadVideo(
  videoId: string,
  outputPath: string
): Promise<void> {
  const video = await ytdl(videoId);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
  video.pipe(writeStream);
}

/**
 * @description Generate a list of random video ids
 * @param {number} count The number of video ids to generate.
 * @returns {string[]}
 * @example generateVideoIds(10);
 */
function generateVideoIds(count: number): string[] {
  const videoIds: string[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const videoId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    videoIds.push(videoId);
  }

  return videoIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be better to use the YouTube API?

Comment: Not a bad idea honestly